# CSS clear only inside parent div

Tags: html, css

Here is the sample code of what I am trying to do

```
<div>
  <div style="float:left; width:220px; height:300px; border: 1px solid #aaa">
  Left div <br>float:left <br> fixed width 220px
  </div>

 <div>
    Right div. <br>No styles<br> Takes remaning width <br><br>
    There are some small blocks (one - four) with "float:left"


  <div class="small">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
    <div>four</div>
  </div>

  <div>
   <div id='bottom_div1'>Some content which needs to appear below small blocks</div>
   <div id='bottom_div2'>Some content at the bottom, which needs to appear below small blocks</div>
  </div>

 </div>

</div>
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7fews2z0/2/)

I need the content inside the divs bottom_div1 and bottom_div2 to appear in the right div below the line of small blocks ("one" - "four").
However with "clear:both" it appears below the left div, and with "clear:none" it appears to the right of the small blocks. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: There is typo, sorry! The closing </div> must be deleted above the div with class=small. However, it doesn't affect anything. New fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/7fews2z0/4/

Comment: This works, but the real data will vary widely. The number of small blocks and the size of each block will differ (as well as the users' screens' width). So there is no exact margin to set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `overflow: hidden` to the container of small divs.

**WHY IT WORKS?**

`overflow: hidden` (and values other than visible) creates a "[block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)" so all floating divs are now contained inside and floating no longer affects the flow.

```css
.small div {float:left; padding:10px; border: 1px solid #aaa}
.small {overflow: hidden}
```

```html
<div>
    <div style="float:left; width:220px; height:300px; border: 1px solid #aaa">
        Left div <br>float:left <br> fixed width 220px
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>Right div. <br>No styles<br> Takes remaning width <br><br> There are some small blocks (one - four) with "float:left"</div>
    </div>

    <div class="small">
        <div>one</div>
        <div>two</div>
        <div>three</div>
        <div>four</div>
    </div>

    <div id='inner-footer'>
        <div id='bottom_div1'>Some content at the bottom, which needs to appear below small blocks</div>
        <div id='bottom_div2'>Some content at the bottom, which needs to appear below small blocks</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dear Mr. Andrew Sklyarevsky and Mr. strah. Both your solutions work fine. Could you explain (or post a link to read) which way is better (more cross-browser and less vulnerable to variations of the data inside those divs)

Comment: @PhantomLord Yes Sir :-)

Comment: Many thanks for "why it works"!!!! Otherwise it seemed like black magic :))

Answer (score 2):

Try `display: inline-block` for the rule `.small div`, e.g.:

```
.small div {display: inline-block; padding:10px; border: 1px solid #aaa}
```

And remove the `clear` styles for `bottom_div1` and `bottom_div2`. Seems to work as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You've very almost got it. You just need to re-arrange your divs and the styles a little bit. Compare the snippet below with your original setup and spot the differences:

```css
.left-div {
float:left;
width:220px;
height:300px;
border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.right-div {
float:left;
width: 300px;
}

.small div {
float:left;
padding:10px;
border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

#bottom_div1,
#bottom_div2 {
clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">

<div class="left-div">
Left div<br>
float:left<br>
fixed width 220px
</div>


<div class="right-div">
Right div.<br>
Only styles are float:left and width: 300px<br>
Takes remaning width<br><br>
There are some small blocks (one - four) with "float:left"

<div class="small">
<div>one</div>
<div>two</div>
<div>three</div>
<div>four</div>
</div>

<div id="bottom_div1">Some content at the bottom, which needs to appear below small blocks</div>
<div id="bottom_div2">Some content at the bottom, which needs to appear below small blocks</div>

</div> <!-- End of .right-div -->
 
</div> <!-- End of .parent-div -->
```

Comment: No. With "float" property the whole right div will move below the left div. This is why it has no properties to make it take the remaining width at the right.

Comment: That rather depends of the width of the right div. ;-)

Comment: I have added an explicit width of `300px` to the right div in the snippet above, so you can see what I mean. Generally, a good rule-of-thumb is that whenever you float an element you should _always_ explicitly specify its width.

Comment: If you wanted the right div to take up the whole of the rest of the horizontal space you could declare its width as: `width: calc(100% - 220px);`